# Keep div toggle state after page reload using checkboxes

Tags: jquery

I have been trying to solve this for sometime but can't quite combine what I have. The page is dynamic and info will be loaded from db. I have a checkbox with call(class=registerbut) that toggles(reveals) a div(hidey) directly below it when checked. It works fine but after page reload all of the divs(hidey) are shown regardless of checked state. I just want the ones that were checked to remain shown and not all.

```
<div style="width:150px; float:left; padding:0px 0 0px 10px;">
<b>Approve</b><br />
<b>Day 1</b><input type="checkbox" name="" value=""/>
<b>Day 2</b><input type="checkbox" name="" value=""/><br />
<b>Day 3</b><input type="checkbox" name="" value=""/>
<b>Day 4</b><input type="checkbox" name="" value=""/><br />
<b>Day 5</b><input type="checkbox" name="" value=""/>
<b>Day 6</b><input type="checkbox" name="" value=""/><br />
<b>Day 7</b><input type="checkbox" name="" value=""/>
<b>Day 8</b><input type="checkbox" name="" value=""/><br />
<b>Approve All Dates</b><input type="checkbox" name="" value=""/><br />

<br />
</div>
<input type="checkbox" class="registerbut" name="toggle" style="margin-top:8px;">Approve


<div class="hidey" style="width:500px; float:left;margin-bottom:10px; padding:0px 0 0px 10px;height:20px; display:none;">
<b>This is where we can put the information for e-signature part of the deal</b><br />
</div>
```

This makes sure that the next/following div(hidey) is the only revealed div.

```
$('.registerbut').change(function(){
    $(this).next('.hidey').toggle();})
```

And the following keeps the div(hidey) still shown on page reload - but it then shows all "hidey" divs regardless of checked state.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.hidey').toggle($(".registerbut").is(":checked"));});

$(".registerbut").click(function() {
$('.hidey').toggle('fast');});
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You will have to store the state somewhere.  It doesn't look like you are using ASP.NET so you can't use session or view state and you probably can't use HTML5 storage yet so....it's cookies!

Comment: Thanks. I have'nt worked with cookies before. What would be the best way to go about it? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/xEfRK/

Update the `.change` method to use show/hide explicitly based on checked state instead of using `.toggle`:

```
if ($(this).is(":checked"))
```

Then, `$(".registerbut").trigger('change');` on page load will work just like you need.

Comment: Thanks, EP! It works. Took me a bit but understand how you did it. I changed the show/hide to $hidey.slideDown("fast"); and $hidey.slideUp("fast"); and it seems to work fine. I guess it can work without cookies? Thanks again.